# How reliable are JSON transfers over HTTP?

Tags: json, http, reliability

Are JSON responses ever incomplete because of server errors, or are they designed to fail loudly? Are there any special concerns for transferring very large sets of data over JSON, and can they be mitigated? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: There's nothing magic about json as compared to any other data format you send across HTTP.

Comment: Do my questions therefore depend on languages and library implementations of HTTP transfers?

Comment: I believe you are confusing HTTP with TCP or UDP.  And to answer your comment, no.  The browser is in charge of that.  The libraries just make it easier for you to utilize it.

Comment: And your choice of server, client, network, router, firewall, ......... but not on the fact that it's json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transferring JSON over HTTP is no different than transferring any bytes over HTTP.

Yes, server errors can result in incomplete transfers. Imagine turning your server off half way through a transfer. This is true of any network transfer. Your client will fail loudly if there is such an error. You might get a connection time out or an error status code. Either way you will know about it.

There is no practical limit to the amount of data you can transfer as JSON over HTTP. I have transferred 1GB+ of JSON data in a single HTTP request. When making a large transfer you want to be sure to use a streaming API on the server side. Which is to say write to the output stream of the HTTP response while reading the data from your db, rather than reading your data from the DB into RAM entirely and then encoding it to JSON and writing it to the output. This way your client can start processing the response immediately, plus your server wont run out of memory.